# C++ to assembly, GCC vs CL

Tags: disassembly, assembly, c++, disassemblers, gcc

I have following C++ code:

```
int main(){

  int a = 1;
  double d = 1.2;

  return 0;
}
```

and get the following assembly using GCC 6.2 -m32:

```
main:
        lea     ecx, [esp+4]
        and     esp, -8
        push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    ecx
        sub     esp, 20
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 1
        fld     QWORD PTR .LC0
        fstp    QWORD PTR [ebp-24]
        mov     eax, 0
        add     esp, 20
        pop     ecx
        pop     ebp
        lea     esp, [ecx-4]
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   858993459
        .long   1072902963
```

and using MS CL 19:

```
_d$ = -12                                         ; size = 8
_a$ = -4                                                ; size = 4
_main   PROC
        push     ebp
        mov      ebp, esp
        sub      esp, 12              ; 0000000cH
        mov      DWORD PTR _a$[ebp], 1
        movsd    xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@3ff3333333333333
        movsd    QWORD PTR _d$[ebp], xmm0
        xor      eax, eax
        mov      esp, ebp
        pop      ebp
        ret      0
_main   ENDP
```

I have several questions.

1. what's  mean first three lines in GCC version?

   `lea     ecx, [esp+4]`

   `and     esp, -8`

   `push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4]`
2. MS CL version allocates 12 bytes, 4 for int and 8 for double:

   `sub      esp, 12  // that's great.`

   But why GCC allocates 24?

   `push ecx`

   `sub esp, 20`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you didn't specify any optimization flag and used -m32, GCC performed no optimization on your code. The -m32 flag specifies the generation of a 32 bit code for a compiler configured to generate 64 bit code by default. In 32 bit mode, even with optimizations activated, GCC will generate a sub-optimal code given that the only way to do floating point computations in 32 bit mode on Intel machines is through [x87](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87) instructions. If you remove the -m32 flag and add -O3 (third level of optimization in GCC) you'll obtain the following assembly code (quite similar to the one generated by Microsoft's CL) :

```
.LC1:
        .string "%d %lf\n"
        .section   .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movl    $1, %esi
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        movl    $1, %eax
        call    printf
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .section   .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
        .align 8
.LC0:
        .long   858993459
        .long   1072902963
```

**Note :** I added a **printf** to the code because if the GCC optimization pass sees no use of the two variables, they will be removed (dead code elimination). I invite you to check out my post on the subject of optimized vs. non optimized code ([Assembly Code - GCC optimized vs not](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/assembly-code-gcc-optimized-vs-not)).

You can also notice that CL used an *XMM* register to store the 64 bit *double* element stored in .LC0. *XMM* registers are part of the SSE (Streaming SIMD Extensions) instruction set used mainly for floating point scalar & vector operations. Its implementation is much cleaner and faster than the x87 instruction set.

Q1 :

```
lea     ecx, [esp+4]      //load the content of [esp + 4] into ecx
and     esp, -8           //align the stack pointer to 8 bytes (same as esp & ~7)
push    DWORD PTR [ecx-4] //push the content of [ecx - 4] on the stack 

[ecx - 4] = [[esp + 4] - 4]
```

Let's suppose the stack is in this state :

```
     |       main      |
     |      return     |
     |      address @  |
     +-----------------+  <--- esp + 4 ---> ecx
     |    some value   |
     +-----------------+  <--- esp = ebp
```

The first instruction puts the existing stack content (main return address @) in ecx. It is equivalent to this :

```
mov ecx, esp
sub ecx, 4
mov ecx, [ecx]
```

You can see that the lea instruction does in one take what these instructions do in three takes.

The second instruction aligns esp on an 8 byte boundary. What that means is that the lower 3 order bits of the address pointed by esp will be 0. Memory accesses are faster on Intel machines when aligned on a power of 2 boundary.

The third instruction changes the state of the stack to the following :

```
     |         @       |
     +-----------------+  <--- esp + 4 ---> ecx
     |    some value   |
     +-----------------+  <--- ebp
     |       @ - 4     |  
     +-----------------+  <--- esp
```

Therefore, when the main function is done, it will return to @ - 4.

Q2 :

Let's reason mathematically :

```
         We have : EBP = ESP0 
         push ecx implies ESP1 = ESP0 - 4 
         then : ESP2 = ESP1 - 20 
         therefore : ESP0 = ESP2 - 24
         mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 1 implies x = EBP - 12 = ESP0 - 12
         We know that ESP0 = ESP2 - 24
         Therefore x = ESP2 - 24 - 12 = ESP2 - 36
         fstp    QWORD PTR [ebp-24] implies y = EBP - 24 = ESP0 - 24
         Therefore y = ESP2 - 24 - 24 = ESP2 - 48
```

Now, from this demonstration we extracted the location of the integer *x = ESP2 - 36*, and the location of the double *y = ESP2 - 48*.
To compute the distance between both variables, we subtract y from x and obtain the following : *x - y = ESP2 - 36 - ESP2 + 48 = 48 - 36 = 12*. And that's the amount of bytes used by GCC for storing both of your 32 bit/4 byte and 64 bit/8 byte variables.

Comment: Thanks, why we have this three lines in GCC 32-bit mode and don't have in 64-bit mode.
What is the purpose of this three lines?

Comment: Check the Q1 update